# Аргументы имеют неверный тип. Фильтрация по дате

Tags: delphi, access, ado, фильтрация, фильтр

```
ADOTable1.Filter:= '[Дата] = '+ DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
ADOTable1.filtered:=true;
```

Помогите пожалуйста, заблудился в трех соснах.

Организую фильтр через adotable1 по полю дата. Выше пример. код простейший. Однако при фильтрации выдает : "аргументы имеют неверный тип" и тд. Думаю ошибка в формате передаваемой даты, однако как это исправить не могу понять. При чем данный алгоритм фильтра работает везде кроме конкретного проекта. Использую ado и access. Формат полей в бд - дата время. Формат поля пробывал менять в бд- не помогло.

Comment: Боюсь что строковое представление даты в разных субд разное, даже для одной СУБД формат даты может быть настраиваемым. Нужно что бы строковое представление даты совпадало с тем которое характерно для даной СУБД.

Comment: @nick_n_a Дело в том , что в самой бд стоит формат dd.mm.yy, ниже я вроде как форматировал дату и пиккера тоже в dd.mm.yy, однако принимать приложение это не хочет

Answer (score -1):

Проблема оказалась на стороне windows. Необходимо в панели управления поменять формат представления даты на аналогичный в access и delphi.

Comment: Я бы предложил "вычислять" формат даты запросом, для каждой субд запрос свой.

Comment: В задании нужно было использовать именно adotable

Comment: За необходимость менять пользовательские я бы на месте преподавателя поставил бы неуд, а на месте работодателя - не оплатил бы ваш труд. Функция DateToStr имеет второй параметр - настройки форматов, в том числе даты и времени, для данной конкретной операции. Также есть функция FormatDateTime, которая принимает строку форматирования в более удобной форме.

Comment: Я сам понимаю , что это костыль. Ваш вариант пробовал самый первый-  не смог победить ошибку - there is no overloaded version of DatetoStr

Comment: @Герман Борисов 
DateTimeToString(formattedDateTime, 'dd/mm/yy', DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
ADOTable1.Filter:=ADOTable1.Filter +'and [Äàòà] = '+ formattedDateTime;

Так синтаксис верный?

Comment: @Герман Борисов 
Только при таком варианте вся та же ошибка "аргументы имеют неверный тип" и тд. Подскажите пожалуйста, если сможете, как грамотно реализовать код?

Comment: почему не использовать Parameters?

Comment: @element111.Если не ошибаюсь, все SQL-сервера понимают дату в формате 'yyyy-mm-dd'. И про кавычки вы забыли. `ADOTable1.Filter:= '[Дата] = '+''''+FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', DateTimePicker1.DateTime)+'''';`